# Redirect IP to url for ISPConfig 3 administration

Tags: ssl, redirection, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am running a debian machine with ISPConfig 3.0.4.3. Yesterday I purchased a RapidSSL wildcard certficate and want to make sure my IPSConfig always loads the admin.mydomain.net url. Even if the user connects to the IP, I want the IP to re-route to the page.

How can I do this? I added the following in the top of my `000-ispconfig.vhost` file, but I got the `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long` error.

What I added:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443>
        ServerName admin.mydomain.net
        ServerAlias mydomain.net
        Redirect permanent / https://admin.mydomain.net
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I make a https connection on my IP adress redirect the user to admin.mydomain.net?

Comment: Have you tried using *:443 instead of the ip?

Comment: I do not want every SSL connection to redirect to this page. Only when the IP address is accessed directly I want the user to be redirected.

Comment: Is mod_ssl enabled and properly working for other pages?

Comment: Yes. Mod_ssl is enabled and SSL is working on the server. See http://bit.ly/GBKsJP